# Adding methods dynamically to a class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to inject a method dynamically to an external class in typescript.
I am getting below error.

error TS2339: Property 'modifyLogger' does not exist on type 'extclass'.

**Code:**

```
    extclass['modifyLogger'] = function(mylogger:any){

     }

    interface extclass{
        modifyLogger(): void;
     }


     let obj = new extclass();
      obj.modifyLogger(log);
```

The above code is giving me error

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using

`extclass.prototype['modifyLogger'] = function(mylogger:any){ }`

in place of your code above.

Also, please correct the declaration of modifyLogger() in the interface which should accept a parameter.

```
interface extclass{
    modifyLogger(arg: any): void;
}
```

**Update**
Please refer to the updated [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeAXUkYG9oFgBQ0-UQFMJEAKASmjRx32gF8dHsBLAOyICcAzMYQuEhRQqtfAFsA9gBMW3AJ4AZSQHMVhThQBc0AG6SW0gNxMa2YTAAqxRKNz5gktiU4BXYIkmbKGMXTwIyOBQAHQADpySnojyYYQA2gDkUrIKymoaiQC60AC80NyubB4sTtAUdv5V0GAgGmSJABYsieQm9lXM1XpgnNCSAEYAVnnQbIQA7oJBqBTt3YNDISlySqrq3vP4zMw4ur0Eo+NT1iRzQA)

```
class Extclass { 
    test() {

    }
}
interface Extclass {
    modifyLogger(): void;
}

class Test {
    constructor() { 
        Extclass.prototype['modifyLogger'] = function () {
            alert('hi');
        }
        var obj = new Extclass();
        obj.modifyLogger();
    }
}

var t = new Test();
```

Comment: I am getting the same error even after making above changes.

Comment: Take a look at the typescript playground. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=19&pln=11&pc=22#code/MYGwhgzhAECmAeAXUkYG9oF8CwAoPCy4UAdAA4BOA9ojQJ5mwDaA5ALZUAmAlgGZ0AZKgHNhsCiwC60ALzReAVwB2wRNypLoACjZ0QIsRQBc0MEroBKaGjw58ubksTjeYYLDhIUUG7mj-oDh5+IVFxLTAKYRMzSxMANypuTgBuPACsPDwQWERoKgAjACtZaCVYAHdPIlQtCzTcQqKSIL5BA3CAIn1hTvqgA)

Comment: I have put my code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECmAeAXUkYG9oF8CwAoAlgLYAOA9gE6LRoLLhSbTQBm5ph0A5AHQD0tKKJwDceQTEIBPAML0IaPHiZNgpAHYRE5AK7BEFABQBKJcuULcZq6atWBc7sTb7Ek4rADanQqQAm+ZkkAGVIAc1DYck4AXWgAXhZtNT18dWgDKRAwiPIALmgwNUkjahtbZTAQSMQDTgAJfE4jUUtysxxWtuh8NURI5jBgWDgkcQsuph9-QJDwyIMwclD8wuL8gDdSfF8WiaZGaDK2qqpSACMAK3joNVgAdxG6VGNdvfOL7imA4Oz5gCIsqE-s1FJ0rB1QZDcEA). Can you check pls?

Comment: `class Extclass { 
    test() {

    }
}

interface Extclass {
    modifyLogger(): void;
}
Extclass.prototype['modifyLogger'] = () => {
    alert('Hi');
}

var obj = new Extclass();
obj.modifyLogger();
`